# Overriding Shipping Email on SOOrder screen on Shipment Settings tab

Tags: acumatica, avalara

I have create a custom contact field on SOOrder summary, so that user can select the Customer Contact based on the Customer selected.

Here is the custom Contact field definition on SOOrder Extension-

```html
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
 LeftJoin<BAccount2, On<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>,
 Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.person>,
       Or<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.lead>>>>),
 DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.contactType, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.bAccountProperty>,
  And<Where<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
    Or<Current<SOOrder.customerID>, IsNull>>>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactBAccountDiff)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where2<Where2<
     Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.person>,
      Or<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.lead>>>,
     And<
      Where<BAccount2.type, IsNull,
       Or<BAccount2.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
        Or<BAccount2.type, Equal<BAccountType.prospectType>,
        Or<BAccount2.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>>>>,
  And<WhereEqualNotNull<BAccount2.bAccountID, SOOrder.customerID>>>), "Contact '{0}' ({1}) has sales order for another business account.", typeof(Contact.displayName), typeof(Contact.contactID))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactInactive, typeof(Contact.displayName))]
[PXDBChildIdentity(typeof(Contact.contactID))]
public virtual int? UsrCustContactID { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustContactID : IBqlField { }
```

Now, I have override the Email with the email of the selected Contact from custom Contact field, on Shipment Settings tab of SOOrder screen whenever the user selects any Contact. I have written below code for it, but seems it is not working.

```html
protected virtual void SOOrder_UsrCustContactID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
 SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

 SOOrderExtension ext = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(Base.Document.Current);

 Contact custContact = PXSelect<Contact,
  Where<Contact.contactID, Equal<Required<Contact.contactID>>>>.Select(graph, ext.UsrCustContactID);

 if (custContact != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(custContact.EMail))
 {
  graph.Document.Current = Base.Document.Current;

  Base.Shipping_Contact.Current.OverrideContact = true;
  Base.Shipping_Contact.Current.Email = custContact.EMail;

  graph.Shipping_Contact.Current = Base.Shipping_Contact.Current;

  graph.Shipping_Contact.Current.OverrideContact = true;
  graph.Shipping_Contact.Current.Email = custContact.EMail;

  Base.Shipping_Contact.Update(graph.Shipping_Contact.Current);
  
  graph.Actions.PressSave();
 }
}
```

There are two issues in this.

1. It does shows the email populated when I select the Contact but when I save, it overrides with the default one from Customer.
2. If I am creating a new Sales Order and select the Contact. While saving if I miss any mandatory fields or any other error come such as Avalara error, then it again overrides the default one from Customer.

Please suggest.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy customer contact email into the shipping address email field, your ***SOOrder_UsrCustContactID_FieldUpdated*** handler should be implemented as follows:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected void SOOrder_UsrCustContactID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var contact = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOOrderExtension.usrCustContactID>(
            sender, e.Row) as Contact;
        if (contact != null)
        {
            var shippingContact = (SOShippingContact)Base.Shipping_Contact.Select();
            shippingContact.OverrideContact = true;
            shippingContact = Base.Shipping_Contact.Update(shippingContact);
            shippingContact = (SOShippingContact)Base.Shipping_Contact.Select();
            shippingContact.Email = contact.EMail;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, the **Update** method called on the **Shipping_Contact** data view after we set **OverrideContact** to ***true***, followed by an additional select from the **Shipping_Contact** view. It is an absolute must to call the **Select** method second time because when **OverrideContact** is set to true, the system creates a new instance of the **SOShippingContact** DAC and inserts it into the cache. The easiest way to obtain the new **SOShippingContact** instance from the cache is via the **Select** method on the **Shipping_Contact** data view.